# I can see network printers when connected via ethernet, but not through a Time Capsule

Tags: network, time-machine, printing

I wish to print to a network printer. When I plug the ethernet cable directly into my laptop (macbook pro 2013, OS X Mavericks) I see all printers available.

However when I try to connect via Time Capsule i.e. (MBP->TC->ethernet) I don't see any printers anywhere.

Any ideas on how I can rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your Time Capsule in bridge mode and it won't create a new network segment. That will make all connections to the TC equivalent to plugging them each in to a switch connected by ethernet.